# How to avoid duplicate entries in Array with case sensitive and case insensitive mixed Strings in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, duplicates, nsfetchrequest

I have a tableview that displays a list of objects of type String, using Core Data, where the user can keep adding new objects to that same table. There´s one limitation, though, which is not allow to add duplicates. I managed to avoid duplicates that are the same for example: "Bank"/"Bank". Problem is I also need to block duplicates like this: "Bank"/"bAnk" or "Bank"/"BAnk" and so on, but I have no idea of how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
 func checkDuplicates(catName: String) -> Bool {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    var contents = [NSManagedObject]()
    var items = [String]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Categories")
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        contents = results as! [Items]
        for item in contents {
            items.append(item.valueForKey("name") as! String)
        }
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

    if items.contains(catName) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

It returns a Bool so that when it returns a duplicate I display an Alert telling the user he can add a duplicate.

So anyone can help my with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to fetch *all* objects in order to check for existing Core Data objects. You can create a fetch request
with a *predicate* which searches for objects with the given name:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Categories")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name ==[c] %@", catName)
```

Here `==[c]` stands for case-insensitive comparison.

An in fact you don't have to fetch objects at all. You can
check for matching objects with `countForFetchRequest()`:

```
var error : NSError? = nil
let count = managedContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
if count == NSNotFound {
    print("error:", error!.localizedDescription)
    return false
} else if count >= 1 {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

This is much more effective because the fetch request is executed 
as a "SELECT COUNT ..." query on the SQLite level, without fetching
the objects into memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can Lowercase both the Strings for comparison to avoid case sensitive issues:

```
let Item_Name = item.valueForKey("name") as! String
items.append(Item_Name.lowercaseString);
```

and

```
if items.contains(catName.lowercaseString) {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your custom logic for the `contains` method. Look

```
let animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Fish"]
let newAnimal = "dog"
let duplicate = animals.contains { $0.lowercaseString == newAnimal.lowercaseString }
print(duplicate) // true
```